# Why is the variable declared inside the JS class `undefined`

Tags: javascript, class

Trying to create a class in JS with the attribute weight in the following code:

```
function Foo() {
    var weight = 10;
    console.log(weight);
}
```

When I instantiate it with `var bar = new Foo();`, `10` is logged to the console.

When I later call `console.log(bar.weight);`, `undefined` is logged to the console. Why is that? I was under the impression that the attributes declared within a JS class were public by default?

Comment: A variable is not a property.

Comment: This is not Java, you have to use `this.weight` explicitly.

Comment: `var` always declares a variable in that scope, no matter how or where a function is called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you haven't actually set `weight` as a property of `bar`; it's merely a local variable created upon the constructor call (this differs from some other languages, like Java, for example). To create it as a property, you need to use the keyword `this`:

```
function Foo() {
    this.weight = 10;
}
```

That sets `weight` to be a property of `Foo` objects, including `bar`, so you should be able to use `console.log(bar.weight)` without issue.

```js
function Foo() {
  this.weight = 10;
}

var bar = new Foo();

document.body.innerHTML = "<code>bar</code>'s weight property is equal to " + bar.weight + ".";
```

Comment: Thanks. Basically the same answer as everybody else. But I think this one was the best. (Accepting when the time limit is passed)

Answer (score 3):

Because weight is not property of Food but a local variable, Change

```
var weight = 10;
```

to

```
this.weight = 10;
```